# Converting HTML to Jade

Tags: html, node.js, tumblr, pug

I'm writing a Node.js application (using Jade and Express) that fetches posts from a Tumblr blog and displays them. Unfortunately, Tumblr sends my site a block of raw HTML, which shows up as such on the main page (which is *where* it should be, only **it's still a block of raw HTML**).

How would I go about converting this block of raw HTML into what I need?

Comment: didn't my last answer help you?

Comment: It did! Thanks! Sorry for the delay, I got caught up in other things. Accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `!{}` to display it as HTML

```
.content !{post.content}
```